# Starting Android SDK Manager in Eclipse throw a Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

When i try to start the Android SDK Manager in Eclipse (and also Console) i get this Exception

```
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/archquery/Main
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.archquery.Main
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/archquery/Main
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.archquery.Main
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[2013-01-19 22:43:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdkmanager/Main
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.sdkmanager.Main
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[2013-01-19 22:43:48 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I don't know what caused it but reinstalling of Eclipse and the adt Plugin and the download a new Version of the SDK couldn't solve the Problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: You may try to delete the workspace .metadata directory and re-import all the projects.

Comment: You seem to have missing classes on the classpath. Do you have a class `com.android.archquery.Main` in your project? Does it have any errors? Is it on the project classpath?

Comment: i think it's nothing with my projects or with the workspace .metadata directory. I try to start the Android SDK Manager with the Terminal and i got the same Exception.

Comment: Difficult to tell what's wrong. Could be a permission problem, launch as admin could work then (removing the SDK install dirs before doing a re-install would get rid of any stale stuff). The JRE could also be a candidate to check, even though that doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: Ok now it's working again. Thanks for your help. At the moment I have no idea what caused the problem, but I could imagine what was the problem. I test it and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everything is working normal now (and the Android SDK Manager starts normal).
What i tried:
I downloaded the SDK Tools only package and tried to start the sdk Manager via the terminal. Everything worked great. Then moved into my folder and it did not work. It turned out that the error was caused by a slash in a folder name. Really strange and hard to find.
Hope it helps